# How to assign RBAC permissions to system:anonymous service account in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cloud

> How to assign RBAC permissions to system:anonymous service account in Kubernetes?

To understand Kubernetes, I want to assign permissions to the `system:anonymous` service account to review permissions using `kubectl auth can-i --list`.

I have created the following role and rolebinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole 
metadata:
  name: anonymous-review-access
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - authorization.k8s.io
  resources:
  - selfsubjectaccessreviews
  - selfsubjectrulesreviews
  verbs:
  - create
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
   name: anonymous-review-access
roleRef:
   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   kind: ClusterRole
   name: anonymous-review-access
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: anonymous
  namespace: default
```

After `kubectl apply -f ...` the above, I'm still not allowed to review access permissions anonymously:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:anonymous -n default
Error from server (Forbidden): selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "selfsubjectrulesreviews" in API group "authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
```

How can I create proper role and rolebinding to view permissions as `system:anonymous` service account?

Answer (score 3):

`system:anonymous` is not a service account.Requests that are not rejected by other configured authentication methods are treated as anonymous requests, and given a username of `system:anonymous` and a group of `system:unauthenticated`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: anonymous-review-access
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - authorization.k8s.io
  resources:
  - selfsubjectaccessreviews
  - selfsubjectrulesreviews
  verbs:
  - create
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
   name: anonymous-review-access
roleRef:
   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   kind: ClusterRole
   name: anonymous-review-access
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: system:anonymous
  namespace: default
```

---

```
    kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:anonymous -n default
Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs   Resource Names   Verbs
selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                  []               [create]
selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io    []                  []               [create]
```

Comment: Are you sure? I've read online it should be a service account. Do I only need to change `subjects.kind` and `subjects.name`? Will you show the correct rolebinding?

Comment: Do you know how I can check for a given username what account is corresponds too? Indeed, I can look service accounts up, but can I also get a list of user accounts, like `system:anonymous`?